# headerDelegate QML tableView - text not visible

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    color:"#292a38"

    TableView
    {
        width: 580

        headerDelegate: Rectangle
                        {
                            id: header1
                            height: 20;
                            color: "#343848"
                        }

        rowDelegate: Rectangle
                    {
                        height: 30

                      }
        TableViewColumn
        {
            role: "selectall"
            title: ""
            width: 40

            delegate:
                    Rectangle
                    {
                        height: 120
                        width: 120
                        color: "#24253c"
                    }
        }

        TableViewColumn
        {
            role: "name"
            title: "Name"
            width: 145

            delegate:
                Rectangle
                {
                    height: 120
                    width: 120
                    color: "#24253c"

                    RowLayout
                    {
                        spacing: 10
                        height: 20
                        width: 20
                        Image
                        {
                            height: 20
                            width: 20
                        }

                        Text
                        {
                            color: "lightgray"
                            text: "something"
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

        TableViewColumn
        {
            role: "size"
            title: "Size"
            width: 100

            delegate: Rectangle
            {
                height: 120
                width: 120
                color: "#24253c"
            }
        }

        TableViewColumn
        {
            role: "last_updated"
            title: "Last Updated"
            width: 300
            delegate: Component
                        {
                            Rectangle
                            {
                                height: 100
                                width: 150
                                id: head
                                color: "#24253c"

                                RowLayout
                                {
                                    spacing: 10
                                    height: parent.height
                                    width: parent.width

                                    Text {
                                        id: name
                                        text: Date().toLocaleString()
                                        color: "lightgray"
                                    }

                                    Image
                                    {
                                        height: 20
                                        width: 20
                                        MouseArea
                                        {
                                            anchors.fill: parent
                                            onClicked: parent.color = "grey"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }


        }

        model: ListModel
                {
                    id: mymodel
                    ListElement { text: "Banana" }
                    ListElement { text: "Apple" }
                    ListElement { text: "Coconut" }
                }
    }

}
```

This results in:

[image]

As you can see the titles of the header are not visible. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header delegates are to be written inside `TableViewStyle` with `style` property and then we are supposed to use `styleData.value` to get the value of individual column titles in the header.

```
TableView
{
    width: 580

    style: TableViewStyle
    {
        headerDelegate: Rectangle
                        {
                            height: 20
                            color: "lightsteelblue"
                            Text {
                                width: parent.width
                                text: styleData.value // <---
                                elide: Text.ElideMiddle
                            }
                        }

        itemDelegate: Rectangle
                      {
                         color: "red"
                         Text {
                             width: parent.width // <---
                             text: styleData.value
                             elide: Text.ElideMiddle
                         }
                      }

        rowDelegate: Rectangle
                        {
                            color: "blue"
                            height: 30
                        }

    }

    TableViewColumn
    {
            role: "selectall"
            title: "XYZ"
            width: 40

    }
}
```